# The atan2 function and axis directions

Tags: trigonometry

In [this ActionScript reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#atan2%28%29) on the `atan2` function, it reads:

> Computes and returns the angle of the point y/x in radians, when
>   measured **counterclockwise** from a circle's x axis (where 0,0 represents
>   the center of the circle). The return value is between positive pi and
>   negative pi. Note that the first parameter to atan2 is always the y
>   coordinate.

For example

```
Math.atan2(0.7071, -0.7071)
```

(note that the first parameter is the Y coordinate) returns 2.356, which is positive Pi*3/4.

But in Flash graphics the Y axis goes down, not up. Shouldn't it be "clockwise" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be clockwise as this would yield positive angles in radians, otherwise there is a contradiction between it being counterclockwise and having positive angle measurements.

Comment: So the docs are wrong?

Comment: You can do it anyway you want, you just need to know that it is that way by one's own definition.